# handler is undefined in nuxt.js

Tags: input, graphql, nuxt.js, handler

this is my template:

```
<template>
    <div> 
      <input type="search" placeholder="search" v-model="searchTerm1" @input="search"  /> 
      <div v-if="searching">
        <div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.slug">
          <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </template>`
```

When i want to search something in input give me this error:

```
handler is undefined`
An error occurred while rendering the page.
Check developer tools console for details.
```

this is my script:

```
 <script>
    import gql from 'graphql-tag';
     const search1 = gql`
     query search($searchTerm1: String) {
       posts(where: { search:$searchTerm1}) {
         edges {
           node {
             slug
             title
           }
         }
       }
     }`;
     export default {
       data() {
         return {
           searchTerm1: '',
           searching: false,
           posts: []
         };
       },
       async search() {
         if  (this.searchTerm1 === '') {
           this.searching = false;
         } else {
           this.searching = true;
           const { data } = await this.$apollo.query({
             query: search1,
             variables: {
               searchTerm1: this.searchTerm1
             }
           })
           this.posts = data.posts.edges.map(edge => edge.node);
         }
       }
     };
   </script>
```